# Firestore cloud functions summing subcollections values

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

sup guys, i'm working on this firebase project and i need to iterate trought a subcollection of all sales of all stores in the root collection and sum their values... the problem that i'm getting is that i'm getting the sum printed before the iteration. I'm new to TS and Firebase... this is what i got so far:

```
export const newBilling = functions.firestore.document('billings/{billId}').onCreate(event => 
{
    const valueArray = []
    const feeArray = []

    const storesCollection = afs.collection('stores').where('active', '==', true).get().then(stores => { 
        stores.forEach(store => {
            const salesCollection = afs.collection('stores').doc(store.id).collection('sales').get().then(sales => {
                sales.forEach(sale => {
                    return valueArray.push(sale.data().value) + feeArray.push(sale.data().fee) 
                    // other aproach 
                    // valueArray.push(sale.data().value)
                    // feeArray.push(sale.data().fee)
                })
            })
        })
    }).catch(error => {console.log(error)})

    let cashbackSum, feeSum : number

    cashbackArray.forEach(value => {
        cashbackSum += value
    })
    feeArray.forEach(value => {
        feeSum += value
    })

    console.log(cashbackSum, feeSum)
    return 0
})
```

TKS =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using promises correctly.  You've got a lot of get() method call, each of which are asynchronous and return a promise, but you're never using them to case the entire function to wait for all the work to complete.  Calling then() doesn't actually make your code wait - it just runs the next bit of code and returns another promise.  Your final console.log is executing first because none of the work you kicked off ahead of it is complete yet.

Your code actually needs to be substantially different in order to work correctly, and you need to return a promise from the entire function that resolves only after all the work is complete.

You can learn better how to use promises in Cloud Functions by going through the [video tutorials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/).

Comment: Thanks Doug! I really thought that .then() would make the function to wait.. watching you right now =)!